# Redirect domain to virtual server with correct URL in browser

Tags: redirect, iis-7.5, domain-name

I have an ASP.NET v4 application running on a virtual server, IIS 7.5, port 8080.  Whilst testing we have behave been connecting using the IP address e.g. http://100.100.100.100:8080

I have now registered a domain name with the same company that provides the virtual server and using their management portal have redirected traffic from the domain name to the ip address and port which works fine.  The URL in the browser however displays the IP address.  How can I get it to display the domain name from the original request?

ADDITIONAL:

The virtual server is running 3 sites in IIS and the particular one for this domain name is running on port 8080 (I cannot change it to port 80).

Answer (score 0):

first of all you may need to switch to port 80 if you dont want to specify the port when you type the domain

secondly make sure your application and/or IIS isnt doing a redirect to the IP regardless of incoming host - if it is, change it to the domains name (and port if still using 8080)

its a good idea to make sure the website you have setup in IIS listens for the domain you registered, this isnt critical while you only have one site on the server but will become critical if you want to add multiple sites to the server

Comment: I have added additional information to my question as I cannot switch to port 80.  How do I know which domains a website is listening for in IIS?

Comment: you should be able to change it to port 80 but you will need to get it to listen for the domain name as well for it to work, you may also have to adjust your other sites to listen for there respective names

Answer (score 0):

This should be achievable. Does the management portal allow you to select different types of redirection? (Ex: Permanent/Temporary/etc) The type you are looking for should say something along the lines of "Hidden - Framed Mask".